# PowerApps - How to get URL to entire Sharepoint list

Tags: powerapps

I'm familiar with PowerApps and working with Galleries to deplay Sharepoint content.  What I can't seem to figure out, is, how can I get a link to allow the user to launch a list view of the entire list, on Sharepoint?

The goal would be to let the user go to Sharepoint to edit data natively there, vs. having to build edit screens for the list natively within the app.  You can link to individual items with no issue, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get a URL for the list itself.

The reason for not doing additional screens for item edits is because in Sharepoint, you can bulk edit data in a grid, whereas PowerApps has no such native mechanism.  I understand I could probably cobble something together, but I'm already concerned about app performance in the total number of controls, and this would probably push it too far.

I looked through all the properties a Sharepoint list exposes in PowerApps, and they all seem to be table-based for the individual list items.

Answer (score 2):

The link to the list is the same as the URL when you look at the list in the browser.

```
http://yourTenant/sites/YourSite/Lists/YourList
```

You can link to a specific view using the view name

```
http://yourTenant/sites/YourSite/Lists/YourList/YourView.aspx
```

Comment: Im trying to get this URL within code/formula, so I'm not hard-coding it in the app somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ideas pop to mind:

1. Insert a button Control with OnSelect Property set to `Launch("http://sharepointSite.com")`.
2. There should be a `{Link}` property exposed for each Sharepoint record in your app. Use `Launch(ThisItem.{Link})` so send user to the Record/List in question.

Comment: Yeah, I use ThisItem."{Link}" to hit individual items.  I suppose another idea is to see if those links can be massaged to go up to the parent list.

Comment: Do you know what the URL syntax is to access a Custom List with its ListId (NOT ITS FRIENDLY NAME)? If so, let me know. I have a PowerApps formula that will transform the item link to list link.

Comment: Welp...[I've been trying to determine the URL for the `AllItems` view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271304/what-is-the-url-for-a-custom-list-with-only-listid/271306?noredirect=1#comment288578_271306) given only `<Sharepoint Site URL>` and `<List ID>`. Doesn't seem possible.